# Directory Tor Browser download

Tags: network-configuration

Seems like there is no Browser on Whonix-Gateway. I might do not understand the proceedure. I downloaded it on Windows base system. Which directory I have to move it in to run from VM Whonix-Gateway? Should I utilise Whonix-Workstation? I do not have it on VM currently installed. I have no inet/browser on Gateway.
I can not undesrtand some of termins. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the Whonix gateway directly. The purpose of Whonix is to seperate out into two distinct virtual machines: the gateway which provides Tor routing, and the Workstation where normal user activies (Browsing, Instant Messaging, etc) are performed.

You should be using Workstation image along with the Gateway image. The Gateway is there to enforce Tor usage for the Workstation even if the Workstation were hacked or broken in some other way, to avoid leaks.

I believe that by default none of the Gateway's traffic is Tor enforced in any way. Trying to perform your normal operations from it will be no more secure than using it from any other desktop environment.

Use the Workstation image to browse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.My goal was to use Whonix Gateway with Kali (plus a VPN). Gatheway does not connect and therefore, Kali has no connection either. I had found a DOS type "browser", but had no idea of it's purpose, cause I am new in it.

Comment: Another question related to Portable VB Whonix installation. After importing it does not run VB - reference to kernel in error msg. I configured all resources on USB, except RAM, of course.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I've no idea what "Portable VB Whonix" is?

Comment: Regardless, that should probably be a new question for the Whonix people to address.